# jQuery flot data with TimeStamp property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

cant show flot data in browser

```
   var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
    [{ data: capacityList, label: "Capacity(MsgNumber/min)"}],
        {
        series:
           {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
        crosshair: { mode: "x" },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        yaxis: {
            axisLabel: "MsgNumber",
            min: 0
        },
        xaxis: {
            axisLabel: "Time",
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%H:%M",
            tickSize: 1000 * 60 * 60
        }
    });
```

capacityList is an array, a element is a object with properties `DatetimeStamp & MsgNumber`:

```
capacityList[12]
Object
DatetimeStamp: 1345681620000
MsgNumber: 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass an array of arrays with x,y pairs. Then the xaxis time functions will be invoked on the x parameter which is a timestamp.

```
capacityList = [[1345681620000,15]]
```

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html